# How can i access a array buffer through a pointer which is a member of a structure?

Tags: c

I want to access the arr[8] elements through the pointer inside the structure. I did that code but it is showing error. please help me. i have attached the code below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
  int var;
   int *ptr;
} Info;

int arr[8] = { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 8, 6, 4 };
Info x = { 10, &arr[8] };

Info *new_ptr = &x;

void func (Info *new_ptr)
{
   printf ("%d", *(new_ptr->ptr[2]));/* compiler showing error in this line */
 }

int main ()
{
  func (&x);

}
```

Comment: `&arr[8]` is one-past-the-end of the array. You want `&arr[0]` (or just `arr`, which does the same behind the scenes.)

Comment: `new_ptr->ptr` is a `int*`, so `new_ptr->ptr[2]` is an `int`. You can't apply value-of to an `int`. Besides `&arr[8]` is out of bounds.

Comment: Replace `*(new_ptr->ptr[2])` with `(new_ptr->ptr[2])`. The access via `[]` is already like a dereference of the pointer.

Comment: Array size declaration and array item access have nothing in common save for the `[ ]` syntax. The former defines a size, the latter an array index starting with 0 and ending with n-1, where n is the array size.

Comment: Try to interpret the compiler error. It tells you there is a problem with the `*`. Depending on the compiler this message can be helpful or not. Copy & Paste your code into [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/) and check the different compilers. MSVC is useless in this case, gcc and Clang give better error messages.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
   int var;
   int *ptr;
} Info;

int arr[8] = { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 8, 6, 4 };
Info x = { 10, arr };  

void func (Info *new_ptr)
{
   printf ("%d", new_ptr->ptr[2]);
}

int main ()
{
   func (&x);
}
```

you need to learn some basics about the pointers and arrays.

Comment: It is hard to spot the difference, if you do not know, what the error was. As I mentioned in the comment to the question, the `*` in the problematic line, was removed. The access with via `[2]` already uses the value stored at this memory address. So a dereference is not necessary anymore.

Comment: Yes it is, but not for a beginner. The memory access and management is one of the big hurdles you have to take, when learning C++.

Comment: @ThomasWilde do you see C++ here?

Comment: @SubhamDey https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294902/what-is-the-best-way-to-say-thank-you-to-stack-overflow